# NSwagStudio how to save code generation settings

Tags: c#, swagger, code-generation, nswag, nswagstudio

When generating C# client for web api via **NSwagStudio** there is an option to configure settings for achieving desired output. However after exiting the application and running it again you have to setup settings from scratch once again.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to save code generation settings and use them after application restart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you have fine tuned the settings and you are satisfied with the generated output class then you should go to the **File** menu (the only menu in the menubar) and choose **Save** or **Save As**. After that your settings will be persisted into a file, with `*.nswag` extension.

Whenever you restart the **NSwagStudio** it will try to open it automatically on your behalf.